# Onclick toggle switch

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a toggle working. Right now, the two share the same class once selected. How can I manipulate the code so they have different border colors once clicked?

I want Header One to have a green border when selected and Header Two to have a blue border when selected.

```js
$('ul.customize-tabs-home li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().find('li.activeprodborder').removeClass('activeprodborder');
  $(this).addClass('activeprodborder');
});
```

```css
.activeprodborder {
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="customize-tabs-home">
  <div>
    <li class="activeprodborder">
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <h1>Header One</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <h1>Header Two</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('ul.customize-tabs-home li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().find('li.activeprodborder').removeClass('activeprodborder');
  $(this).addClass('activeprodborder');
  if($(this).index() == 0) {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'green');
  } else if($(this).index() == 1) {
    $(this).css('border-color', 'blue');
  }
});
```

```css
.activeprodborder {
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="customize-tabs-home" >
   <div>
      <li>
         <a href="#">
            <div>
               <h1>Header Two</h1>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#">
            <div>
               <h1>Header Two</h1>
            </div>
         </a>
      </li>
   </div>
</ul>
```

Is that what you need?
Instead of checking indexes you can use id to check which header is going to be  toggled.

Comment: Not quite! I want only one to be selected at a time, so it switches between the two. But while I want 'Header One' to have a green border while selected, and I want 'Header Two' to have a blue border while selected.

Comment: @spratt please add that to the question, as every answer so far has made the same assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this is what you're describing, but...

```js
$('ul.customize-tabs-home li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().find('li.activeprodborder').addClass('inactiveprodborder');
   $(this).removeClass('inactiveprodborder');
  $(this).addClass('activeprodborder');
});
```

```css
.activeprodborder {
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid green;
}

.inactiveprodborder  {
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="customize-tabs-home">
  <div>
    <li class="activeprodborder">
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <h1>Header One</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <h1>Header Two</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Almost - but not quite! I want only one to be selected at a time, so it switches between the two. But I want 'Header One' to have a green border while selected, and I want 'Header Two' to have a blue border while selected.

Answer (score 0):

Add another style for the common details and just change color for the active state.

You can use `:first-child` and `:last-child` to target each element with a different color. If you end up with more than 2 elements you can use [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) or additional classes.

```js
$('ul.customize-tabs-home li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().find('li.activeprodborder').removeClass('activeprodborder');
  $(this).addClass('activeprodborder');
});
```

```css
/*Common Class*/

.customize-tabs-home li {
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid grey;
}


/*Active*/
.customize-tabs-home li:first-child.activeprodborder {
  border-color: green;
}

.customize-tabs-home li:last-child.activeprodborder {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="customize-tabs-home">
  <li class="activeprodborder">
    <a href="#">
      <div>
        <h1>Header One</h1>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div>
        <h1>Header Two</h1>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also note that `div` is not a valid child for `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the two `li`s to have different colors when clicked on, you should give each of them an `id` so you know which color to add to each of them.

```css
.activeprodborder {
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid green;
}
.secondactiveprodborder{
  border: 4px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="customize-tabs-home">
  <div>
    <li class="activeprodborder" id="headerone">
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <h1>Header One</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="headertwo">
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <h1>Header Two</h1>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
<script>
$('ul.customize-tabs-home li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().find('li.activeprodborder').removeClass('activeprodborder');
  $(this).parent().find('li.secondactiveprodborder').removeClass('secondactiveprodborder');
  var elemId = $(this).attr('id');
  if(elemId=="headerone"){
  $(this).addClass('activeprodborder');
  } else if(elemId=="headertwo"){
  $(this).addClass('secondactiveprodborder');
  } else {
  //default
  }
});
</script>
```